# How to find if table cells don't contain xx

Tags: jquery

I'm looking create a piece of jQuery logic that answers:

> Are there any tables cells that don't contain '' or 'xx' and don't have the class 'yy'

This is my effort - but it seems really messy?:

```
$('td').filter(function(index) {
            return  !$(this).hasClass('yy') &&
                    !($(this).html().trim() == '' || $(this).html().trim() == '');
        })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), for example:

```
$('td:not(.yy):not(:contains(xx)):not(:empty)')
```

This checks for cells that do [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) have the `.yy` class, do [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) contain "xx" and are [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/).

If you *need* to trim, I'm leave the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), for example:

```
$('td:not(.yy)').filter(function() {
  var thtml = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
  return thtml != '' && thtml != 'xx';
});
```

Note I'm using [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) since not all browsers support `String.trim()`.